# Is boric acid aqueous solution corrosive to stainless steel?

Tags: acid-base

I'm thinking of trying an aqueous boric acid solution in a nebulizer for a sinus infection, in a similar strength as for eyewash (anywhere from 1 tsp. in 4 oz. to 1 tsp. in 32 oz.). My nebulizer has a stainless steel screen that the vapor comes thru, and I need to know if the aqueous boric acid solution will have any corrosive effect on the stainless?  Thank you.

Comment: You think anything would sooner damage stainless steel than mucous membrane? Well, in the long run there would be many such things, but not in the short.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Boric acid is one of the weakest acids commonly used. Its $p$K$_a$ is equal to $9.24$. Its solution will have a negligible corrosive effect on the stainless.